# Simple Calculator to add/subtract/multiply/divide 2 inputs

Tags: python

This is for an assignment in my robotics class so the requirements I needed to meet was that it had to be in a while loop and the input numbers needed to be float point. I just want to make sure that I'm not using any bad practices and if there are any areas that can be improved.

```
while (True):
    # Gets operator, converts to int and breaks if its not a number
    try: operator = int(input("Choose an Operator:\n1) Addition\n2) Subtraction\n3) Multiplication\n4) Division\nInput (1/2/3/4):"))
    except:
        print('Invalid Input: Choose A Valid Operation')
        break
    
    # Checks the operator is within 1 and 4
    if operator > 4 or operator < 1: 
        print('Invalid Input: Choose A Valid Operation')
        break
    
    # Gets first and second number, converts numbers to float and breaks if its not a number
    try: firstnum = float(input('First Number:'))
    except: 
        print('Invalid Input: Not a valid number')
        break
    try: secondnum = float(input('Second Number:'))
    except: 
        print('Invalid Input: Not a valid number')
        break
    
    if operator == 1:
        print('{0} + {1} ='.format(firstnum, secondnum), end =" ")
        print(firstnum + secondnum)
        break
    if operator == 2:
        print('{0} - {1} ='.format(firstnum, secondnum), end =" ")
        print(firstnum - secondnum)
        break
    if operator == 3:
        print('{0} * {1} ='.format(firstnum, secondnum), end =" ")
        print(firstnum * secondnum)
        break
    if operator == 4:
        print('{0} / {1} ='.format(firstnum, secondnum), end =" ")
        print(firstnum / secondnum)
        break
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Formatting strings in Python

```py
foo = 5
print('{foo}'.format(foo))
```

This is a nice way to format string, But there is a short and cleaner way to format strings in Python 3 known as the [f-String](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). The problem with `str.format()` is that if you have multiple parameters. Your string starts to look a little werid.For example

```py
first_name = "Eric"
last_name = "Idle"
age = 74
profession = "comedian"
affiliation = "Monty Python"
print(("Hello, {first_name} {last_name}. You are {age}. " + 
        "You are a {profession}. You were a member of {affiliation}.") \
        .format(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, age=age, \
               profession=profession, affiliation=affiliation))
```

With [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). The same would look like.

```py
print(f"Hello, {first_name} {last_name}. You are {age}. " +
      f"You are a {profession}. You were a member of {affiliation}.")
```

This is why you should prefer using [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

## `eval` in Python

When you want to perform the arithmetic part, I see that you have used a thread of if-statements. But we can use Python's [eval](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/eval-in-python/) function to make life much easier. We simple place the operator entered by the user un between the two numbers.

### old

```py
if operator == 1:
    print('{0} + {1} ='.format(firstnum, secondnum), end =" ")
    print(firstnum + secondnum)
    break
if operator == 2:
    print('{0} - {1} ='.format(firstnum, secondnum), end =" ")
    print(firstnum - secondnum)
    break
if operator == 3:
    print('{0} * {1} ='.format(firstnum, secondnum), end =" ")
    print(firstnum * secondnum)
    break
if operator == 4:
    print('{0} / {1} ='.format(firstnum, secondnum), end =" ")
    print(firstnum / secondnum)
    break
```

We ask the user to enter the operation the want directly , for example

> Choose an operator: +

Or if you want to stick to using numbers.
`operators = operators = {'+':1,'-':2,'*':3,'/':4}`

I have gone with the 1st method. You can use whatever you prefer to

### new

```py
print(f"{firstnum} {operator} {secondnum} = {float(eval(firstnum + operator + secondnum))}")
```

The new code using `eval` would like

```py
operators = ['+','-','*','/']
while (True):
    # Gets operator, converts to int and breaks if its not a number
    try: operator = input("Choose an Operator:\n1) Addition\n2) Subtraction\n3) Multiplication\n4) Division\nInput\n(+,-,*,/):")
    except:
        print('Invalid Input: Choose A Valid Operation')
        break

    # Checks the operator is within 1 and 4
    if operator not in operators:
        print('Invalid Input: Choose A Valid Operation')
        break

    # Gets first and second number, converts numbers to float and breaks if its not a number
    try: firstnum = input('First Number:')
    except:
        print('Invalid Input: Not a valid number')
        break
    try: secondnum = input('Second Number:')
    except:
        print('Invalid Input: Not a valid number')
        break

    print(f"{firstnum} {operator} {secondnum} = {float(eval(firstnum + operator + secondnum))}")
```

With that simple change, I removed about 20 lines of code into one. Making it much more readable

## Clearing the screen

It would be nicer to see a clear terminal after finishing one job. There are many ways to clear the terminal in python. A common way for windows users is

```py
os.system('cls')
```

But this way is considered bad as it is quite expensive. You can get away by simply

```py
print(chr(27) + "[2J")
```

Adding this to the start of each iteration in the `while(True):` loop will give a better experience to the user.

## Waiting for input

Lastly, adding this line of code to the end will pause on the current text before going to the next one.
`input("Press any key to continue...")`

Comment: `eval` is a rather unsafe method, _no matter what_. It's unlikely to matter much here. Also, f-strings are only available on Python 3.6+. `input("Press any key to continue...")` will pause until someone presses enter. I think `getch` would be more useful for a "press a key to continue"-type thing. Sorry about criticizing; mine isn't too great either.

Comment: @Someone Any reason to *not* use python 3.6+?

Comment: support. Sometimes a platform may not support Python 3.6+.

Comment: @Someone and which platform ?

Comment: 1. You never know and 2. OnlineGDB. I didn't know of Repl at the time and I suffered due to the lack of f-strings.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the program should stop if a person entered something incorrectly. Also, the part at the end is larger than need be and you don't need the 0 and 1 within the braces as they are added by defalt. Here's a solution(although it uses multiple `while` loops):

```
operators = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
while True:
    # Gets operator, converts to int and breaks if it's a number
    try: operator_switch = int(input("Choose an Operator:\n1) Addition\n2) Subtraction\n3) Multiplication\n4) Division\nInput (1/2/3/4):"))
    except:
        print("Invalid Input: Choose a valid operation")
    else:
        # Checks the operator is within 1 and 4
        if operator_switch > 4 or operator_switch < 1:
            print("Invalid Input: Choose a valid operation")
            continue # goes straight back to the beginning without running what's after
        operator = operators[operator_switch - 1]
        break
while True:
    # Gets first and second number, converts numbers to float and breaks only if it's a number
    try: firstnum = float(input("First number: "))
    except: 
        print("Invalid Input: Not a valid number")
        continue
    try: secondnum = float(input("Second number: "))
    except: 
        print("Invalid Input: Not a valid number")
        continue
    else:
        break
# Shortens the end significantly. Don't read this if you don't want to
op_func = int.__add__ if operator == "+" else int.__sub__ if operator == "-" else int.__mul__ if operator == "*" else int.__div__
print(f"{firstnum} {operator} {secondnum} = {op_func(firstnum, secondnum)}")
```

Comment: When trying it after inputing the two numbers it loops back to asking the first number. I think its not exiting that second while loop.

Comment: The first paragragh is a pretty good answer, there really isn't any need to provide an alternate solution.